# Mvc web api route generation issue

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am trying to generate a url from within one of my web api actions:

```
var resultsModel =
                results.Select(
                    r =>
                        new ResultModel(criteria, 
                            r,
                            Url.Link("Default", new { Controller = "CV", Action = "Get", candidateid = r.CandidateId, filename = r.Name })
                            , false))
                    .ToList();
```

however the genrated url is missing the `"api/"` prepender and therefor does not work as the url cannot be resolved.

```
https://temp-search.recruiter.workstation.local/recruiter/temp-search/cv/get?candidateid=14350164&filename=Douggersby%20Mondays&id=143501
```

the following is my web api config:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MessageHandlers.Add(new AuthorizationHandler());
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referring to the 'Default' route instead of the 'DefaultApi' route.

Instead of:

```
Url.Link("Default", new { Controller = "CV", Action = "Get", candidateid = r.CandidateId, filename = r.Name })
                        , false))
```

Use:

```
Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { Controller = "CV", Action = "Get", candidateid = r.CandidateId, filename = r.Name })
                        , false))
```

And the 'DefaultApi' route template will be used to generate the url, including the api/ prefix.